# AWS, GitHub Action: User is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource(CodePipeline)

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, github-actions

I hope some help from AWS Experts.
I'm going to execute the AWS CodePipeline using GitHub Actions. I'm following [this example](https://github.com/solarmosaic/aws-codepipeline-execute) and I already set the roles for this.
But when I test it, there is an error like this.

***"Error: User: arn:aws:iam::***:user/lms-test is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:codepipeline:us-west-1:***:lms-test"***

To fix this error, I also added `sts:AssumRole` to current user(lms-test), but still same error.
I look forward to getting solution about this problem.

Thanks for your time and consideration.

Comment: The above example uses aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials.  The example given assumes into a role.  You would define a trust policy against this role that allows the action sts:AssumeRole from the Principal Service: codepipeline.amazonaws.com (or similar).  That role then needs to have the appropriate permissions to do what it needs to in CodePipeline.  It's likely the sts:AssumeRole permission also needs to be added to the above user (Resource: '*')

Comment: I already fixed the problem and I just make sure your solution is excellent. Really, thanks.

Comment: No problem, glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 6):

Theres something missing in your trusted policy. Change it as follows:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Federated": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxx:oidc-provider/token.actions.githubusercontent.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "token.actions.githubusercontent.com:aud": "sts.amazonaws.com"
                },
                "StringLike": {
                    "token.actions.githubusercontent.com:sub": "repo:[your-org]/[your-repo]:*"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: More information here https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/security-hardening-your-deployments/configuring-openid-connect-in-amazon-web-services